# How to build an array larger than the nodeList, putting empty strings as placeholders for missing classes?

Tags: javascript, document, selectors-api

HTML

```
<div class="1"><div class="2">element1class2</div><div class="3">element1class3</div></div>
<div class="1"><div class="2">element2class2</div></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var class2List= document.querySelectorAll('div.class1 div.class2')
var class3List= document.querySelectorAll('div.class1 div.class3')
    
for (let i = 0; i < class2List.length; i++) {
            nodes[i] = {
              class2: class2List[i].innerText,
              class3: class3list[i].innerText,
            } 
          }
```

Hi, I'd like to know if it's possible to use querySelectors  make an Array of HTML Elements in the following way:

i'd like an output array of of the the innerText, but when there is no class, to put an empty string.

```
[{class2: 'element1class2', class3: 'element1class3'},
 {class2: 'element2class2', class3: ''} ]
```

right now, if there is no div class="3" in the node, then the NodeList length is reduce by 1 for every element not carrying a class="3" div.

The current output is  `innerText is not defined for class3list` for class3List because the length of class3list is shorter than class2List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use optional chaining so that the value is `undefined` if the element doesn't exist, then use `??` to alternate with the empty string in such a case:

```
class3: class3list[i]?.innerText ?? '',
```

If you can't use optional chaining, you can use the conditional operator:

```
class3: class3list[i] ? class3list[i].innerText : '',
```

If you need to handle "holes" in the middle, then use a different approach: map the `<div class="2"` elements to their next sibling:

```js
const nodes = [...document.querySelectorAll('[class="2"]')]
  .map(class2 => ({
    class2: class2.textContent,
    class3: class2.nextElementSibling?.textContent ?? ''
  }));
console.log(nodes);
```

```html
<div class="1">
  <div class="2">element1class2</div>
  <div class="3">element1class3</div>
</div>
<div class="1">
  <div class="2">element2class2</div>
</div>
```

Note that you need to use the `[class="2"]` selector string, not `.class2`, because your elements are not `class="class2"`, but `class="2"`.

You also need to fix the syntax of your HTML. The final

```
</div>/div>
```

should be

```
</div></div>
```

Comment: the problem is that class2list looks like [1,2,3,4,5] and class3list looks like [1,3,5] (based on parent node) The lengths of the two nodeLists are not equal and when using queryselectorall there is no relative parent associated with the node. I want to match the scraped data with the correct group based on a parent class.

Comment: Probably best to show an example with holes in your question then. See edit, navigate to the adjacent sibling instead

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @certainperformance, I found a solution to my problem by taking the grouping selector (class1) and then mapping each array element with another querySelector for the class I'm looking for (class2 or class3)
for example:

```
const nodes = [...document.querySelectorAll('[class="2"]')]
```

thanks for the hint on the css selector for class=2

```
nodes.map(node => ({
    class2: node.querySelector('[class="2"]') ? node.querySelector('[class="2"]').textContent: '',
    class3: node.querySelector('[class="3"]') ? node.querySelector('[class="3"]').textContent: ''
}))
```

This way we can check if a class exists under the parent node for each parent in the nodeList.